# Issue when merging a Git subtree when a file has been removed

Tags: git, git-merge, git-subtree

I want to use subtrees in one of my projects, and I use the method described [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging). I'm having issues when merging a subtree into my subproject in the case where some files have been removed from the subtree. It seems that the file deletion is not propagated from the subtree integration branch into the master branch during the merge.

I'm running **Git 1.9.1** on **Kubuntu 14.04** and `sub_project` is integrated as `subtree` in my main project.

1. Modify one file and remove another file from my `sub_project`
2. Commit the modification
3. Browse my main project
4. Checkout the sub_project integration branch
5. Pull the modification (I see the modification of the modified file and the deletion of the removed file)
6. Checkout the `master` branch of my main project
7. `git diff-tree -p sub_project_branch` indicates that one file has been modified, and one file has been deleted
8. Perform a merge of my subtree integration branch into master branch (removed file is still there, whereas modification has been integrated)

Here are the corresponding commands:

**Creating project that will be used as subtree**

```
$ mkdir sub_project
$ cd sub_project
$ git init
$ touch toto
$ echo "-----------------" >> toto
$ echo "- toto file">> toto
$ echo "-----------------" >> toto
$ touch tata
$ echo "-----------------" >> tata
$ echo "- tata file">> tata
$ echo "-----------------" >> tata
$ git add toto tata
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
$ echo "echo toto" >> toto
$ echo "echo tata" >> tata
$ git commit -am "Add content to file"
$ cd ..
```

**Creating main project that will use the subtree**

```
$ mkdir main_project
$ cd main_project
$ git init
$ touch tutu
$ echo "-----------------" >> tutu
$ echo "- tutu file">> tutu
$ echo "-----------------" >> tutu
$ git add tutu
$ git commit -m "Add tutu file"
```

**Creating subtree**

```
$ mkdir sources
$ git remote add sub_project_remote ../sub_project
$ git fetch sub_project_remote
$ git checkout -b sub_project_branch sub_project_remote/master
$ git checkout master
$ git read-tree --prefix=sources/sub_project/ -u sub_project_branch
$ git commit -am "Integration of subtree"
```

**Checking that subtree is well integrated**

```
$ ls *
tutu

sources:
sub_project
$ ls sources/sub_project
tata
toto
```

**Go in subtree to remove file tata**

```
$ cd ../sub_project
$ echo "#EOF" >> toto
$ git add toto
$ git rm tata
$ git commit -m "Add EOF and remove tata"
```

**Go back in main project to integrate subtree modifications**

```
$ cd ../main_project
$ git checkout sub_project_branch
$ git fetch sub_project_remote
$ git pull
```

**Check that tata has been removed in subtree**

```
$ ls *
toto
```

**Merge in master branch**

```
$ git checkout master
$ git diff-tree -p sub_project_branch
diff --git a/tata b/tata
deleted file mode 100644
index a4f4cc4..0000000
--- a/tata
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,4 +0,0 @@
------------------
-- tata file
------------------
-echo tata
diff --git a/toto b/toto
index 8dfbe14..98ae756 100644
--- a/toto
+++ b/toto
@@ -2,3 +2,4 @@
 - toto file
 -----------------
 echo toto
+#EOF

$ git merge -v --squash --no-commit -X subtree=sources/sub_project -X theirs sub_project_branch
```

**Check after merge that tata has been removed**

```
$ ls sources/sub_project
tata
toto
```

I was expecting to see in the master branch the modification of the file and the deletion of the other file, but the removed file is still there and tracked. The modification of the file has been done, but it looks like the deletion has not been "merged".

The behaviour I expect is the same that the one illustrated in the command sequence below, which performs exactly the same actions except they are done in a branch instead of a subtree. Toto should have been modified, and tata should no longer be there (or at least not be tracked anymore).

```
#!/bin/sh
$ git init
$ touch toto
$ echo "-----------------" >> toto
$ echo "- toto file">> toto
$ echo "-----------------" >> toto
$ touch tata
$ echo "-----------------" >> tata
$ echo "- tata file">> tata
$ echo "-----------------" >> tata
$ git add toto tata
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
$ echo "echo toto" >> toto
$ echo "echo tata" >> tata
$ git commit -am "Add content to file"
$ git checkout -b headers
$ echo "#EOF" >> toto
$ git add toto
$ git rm tata
$ git commit -m "Add EOF and remove tata"
$ git checkout master
$ touch tutu
$ echo "-----------------" >> tutu
$ echo "- tutu file">> tutu
$ echo "-----------------" >> tutu
$ git add tutu
$ git commit -m "Add tutu file"
$ git merge -m "Merge from headers branch" headers
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 tata | 4 ----
 toto | 1 +
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 4 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 tata
[master a9cad6d] Add EOF
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ echo "#EOF" >> tutu
$ git add tutu
$ git commit -m "Add EOF"
$ ls
toto
tutu
#EOF
```

According to what I see, it seems that the subtree merge is doing a kind of copy instead of a real merge, meaning that if the source file disappears, then the corresponding target file is untouched instead of being deleted.

Is this behaviour correct, or is it my understanding of what a subtree merge should do that is wrong?

I also asked the question on the [Git mailing list](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg251592.html), but I have no answers at the moment.